How to hook up electrical wiring to a heat pump and safety switch to pool pump
My heat pump is 240V on a 30 Amp GFI breaker the pool pump is 120V 30 Amp GFI. What size wire do you use for the safety switch?

Can you get us the actual MCA from the pool heat pump's nameplate, and the nameplate HP of the pool pump?

What do the instructions say?

Best we can do with wire type and label data not supplied is guess #4 for 60A protection for 60 degree rated NM or UF cable.
Wire size on Heat Pumps and motors are calculated independently from overcurrent protection.
If the heat pump and pool pump are on the same feeder you need 125% of MCA or motor amperage from label of the larger load plus 100% of additional . Then we need to know type of wire or cable to determine temperature rating.

30A circuit (GFI or not) is 10AWG copper minimum. Could be 8, could be 6, could be 4, but must be at least 10.
Use a torque driver to tighten the screws on the connections to the specified torque range (neither too loose nor too tight.)
